# Oracle Identity Manager and Microsoft Read-Only Domain Controllers

Tags: active-directory, oracle, identity-management, rodc

Is Oracle Identity Management 11g (OID) compatible with Microsoft Active Directory Read-Only Domain Controllers? (RODC)

My setup has OID importing users from AD RODC. Is this configuration supported?

I read some documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/oid.1111/e10031/odip_int_cons.htm#CJAEEGGB) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/oid.1111/e10031/odip_int_cons.htm#CHDDFFGG) but I could not find anything on what versions of AD are supported by OID.